# Regex: match the function name without the parameter list, and with the template definition

Tags: regex

that sounded like an easy one (and it probably is) but I'm struggling with the following regex challenge.

I'm trying to identify the function name of all the following lines without including the parameter list (so trimming anything between parenthesis). UNLESS if it's part of a template description, that is between '<' and '>'.
Additionally any artefacts after the method name should be ignored...

So far my best try was

```
^[^\(\)]+
```

For instance, here is a typical input covering all my cases:

```
operator()(Name::UI::IKeyListener*) const
notify<void (Name::UI::IMouseListener::*)(Name::UI::MouseEvent const&)>
forEachLoadCommand(Diagnostics&, void 
entry(void*) + 144
```

Output:

```
operator
notify<void (Name::UI::IMouseListener::*)(Name::UI::MouseEvent const&)>
forEachLoadCommand
entry
```

I can't get the second line right, it will return "notify<void " which makes sense... but I do not know how to solve this.

I thought maybe an alternative group would help?

I've got a Regex101 sandbox already available here: https://regex101.com/r/JZvC15/1

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you, it should simply return 'notify' and nothing else on that line?  Just add '<' to your expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional match for template substring i.e. `<...>`:

```sh
^\s*\w+(?:<.*>)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeGc6T/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:<.*>)?`: An optional non-capturing group that matches longest `<...>` substring

Comment: Thanks I will need to take a few minutes to study your Regex to make sure I understand how it works. Unfortunately I forgot that there could be nested <> so it seems to fail in this case. I've updated your Regex link directly I believe https://regex101.com/r/ualR6w/1

Comment: I think that won't be easy as regex are renown for not dealing so well with nested patterns unfortunately. Maybe I need to solve this with other ways then with Regex?

Comment: In fact that seems to work! Thanks. I understand it in the details but couldn't have found this myself with my current knowledge. Will remember this for future uses.

Comment: I've spotted some limitations with the first version that I've also updated. I'm facing a major one here with a quite exotic case. I don't understand why the bracketing of ()? should make sure the <> should only happen once though. https://regex101.com/r/Nlbjwm/2

Comment: Try this `^\s*~?\w+(?:<.*>)?`

Comment: hi sorry it wasn't about the ~ this is working fine. The issue is that the result should be "~destructor<surfaces::panels<'lambda'(std::__1::pair), cursor*>*>" not "~destructor<surfaces::panels<'lambda'(std::__1::pair), cursor*>*>(function_not_included<test>"

It seems the parser will stop at the end of the last <...> pattern while it should stop after the end of the first <...>

Comment: I thought the lazy quantifier could help here but that's somehow too lazy and stops after "... cursor*>".

Comment: `<.*>` has a greedy`.*` so it will match longest string before matching a `>`. A regex cannot handle matching nested `<` and `>` and get to the correct closing `>` for each `<`. For that you will need to write code based parsing.

Comment: Alright then I will switch to this solution! Thank you so much!